# Finding the Article id of a focused article in infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events, jquery-events

I am working on a site with infinite number of articles that are shown one after the another.

I need to create an event for when the user stays on a page for some time (user is pausing to think).

I tried using the `mouseover` event but it won't do because the mouse may or may not be on the article (scrolling or using key actions).

How do I create an event when the page is focused and catch the id/class of the article that has focus?

---

If anyone else in interested in knowing this, it can be done by using:

```
document.elementFromPoint(a,b);
```

set a (a,b) coordinate in the page where the article will be and the `scrollstop` event can be used to capture the article id.

Comment: not clear with your question?

Comment: hi, so the basic gist is i wanted to create an event when the page is focused and catch the id/class of the article shown in page focused.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else in interested in knowing this, it can be done by using :

```
document.elementFromPoint(a,b);
```

set a (a,b) coordinate in the page where the article will be and the "scrollstop" event can be used 
to capture the article id.